# Sending logs from a syslog-ng client to a rsyslog server

Tags: syslog, rsyslog, syslog-ng

I have a setup where logs from a syslog-ng client is sent to a rsyslog server. I want send logs via TCP.
Following is the configuration of my syslog-ng client.

```
destination d_remoteUdp { network("192.168.104.48" transport("udp") port(514));};
destination d_net { tcp("192.168.104.48" port(601) log_fifo_size(1000)); };

 log {source(s_src); destination(d_remoteUdp); };
 log {source(s_src); destination(d_net); };
```

where 192.168.104.48 is the ip of the server.
How to configure rsyslog to receive these logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your rsyslog.conf:

```
# provides TCP syslog reception
module(load="imtcp")
input(type="imtcp" port="601")
```